# How to make equal column height for different hash values of ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, bootstrap-4, rails-activerecord

guys!
There is a puzzle with .erb-view in Sinatra and Bootstrap grid: how to make equal height of columns, which created through "each" cycle?
Value in Row 3 "c" could have various length.

My stack is:
Ruby 2.5.3
Gem Sinatra
Gem Sinatra-Activerecord
bootstrap 4.3.1

I've tried to use various combinations with rows and columns: d-flex class, flex-fill options, text-truncate as last chance, but I understand that is not exactly I need, because columns created for each product item with different data.

1)In app.rb:

```
get'/main' do
  @products = Product.all
  erb :index
end
```

2) In index.erb:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <% @products.each do |prod| %>
    <div class="col-4 p-3 mx-1 mb-5 shadow bg-white rounded" style="min-width: 160px; max-width: 32%">

    <div class="row justify-content-left"><b><%= prod.a%></b></div>

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="<%= prod.b %>" style="justify-content-center"></div>

        <div class="row justify-content-left" style="min-height: 50px">
      <div class="col my-auto py-sm-0" style="min-height: 70px; max-height: 90px">
<i>Description: <%=**prod.c**%></i>
      </div>
    </div>

      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

As a result I need to see 3 columns with equal width and height, and 3 equal rows into each column.
Now, row 3 breaks the solid view.

Comment: why are you inline styling?  also can you add a screenshot somehow illustrating the problem?

Comment: @lacostenycoder Saying inline do you mean rows instead of columns or something else?
Thank you for all comments)

Here is screen of trouble - it appears when page is resizing
[https://pasteboard.co/Irx7Q3r.png](https://pasteboard.co/Irx7Q3r.png)

Comment: This is going to be hard to help you with unless you can share the project or a subset needed to work with your data and styles.  Can you share it along with products data on a github repo or gist or something?